# Keeping log of Linux RedHat 6.3 shutdown messages

Tags: shutdown, redhat-enterprise-linux

with RedHat 6 the services startup messages (i.e. the ones with the neat green [ OK ] tags) are stored in /var/log/boot.log. The shutdown messages are not stored though. Questions:

1 - How can I keep track of all shutdown messages (until disk unmount for obvious reasons), possibly in /var/log/boot.log too?

2 - How can I have those boot.log files rotated at each reboot, so I keep them over time?

3 - Subsidiary question: where is the local7 log facility configured in the startup scripts? This feature is probably the worst-documented Linux feature ever.

Thanks for your help,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

To the first question I have only an idea: using [Upstart](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Technical_Notes/deployment.html) bind the rsyslog service to umount with `stop on stopping filesystems` (or whatever is the service name for umounting the root filesystem (or wherever your logs are), I have no access to a RHEL system right now). At the moment I think rsyslog goes down a lot earlier than just before root filesystem is umounted.

You can use '@reboot' tag on crontab to do whatever you'd like to do at the reboot time, in case you want to rotate `boot.log`. I think this might be adequate solution as when the cron daemon starts up, most or all relevant kernel boot messages are already printed in the kernel message buffer and sent to syslog too. Of course, there is most likely something starting after the cron daemon, so if you rotate your log at when the cron daemon starts, you probably will have something from this boot going to the next version of the file.

Red Hat ships with [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/) which has a main configuration file `/etc/rsyslog.conf` which sources files in the directory `/etc/rsyslog.d`. Whatever is done with the facility LOCAL7, that is the place where it's defined.

Comment: Hi Sami, thanks for the answer. The main issue at that time is that although service messages are sent to syslog at boot time, using local7 facility, they don't seem to be at shutdown: there are no more messages in /var/log/boot.log after startup. This was the point of question #3: where is this local7 facility set?